# Probability of particles being in a state $\epsilon_i$

Tags: probability

I have a set of $N$ particles that can be in two energy states, $\epsilon_1=0$ and $\epsilon_2=\epsilon$. The probability of a particle being in each state is

$$p_1=\frac{1}{1+e^{-\beta\epsilon}}\\
p_2=\frac{e^{-\beta\epsilon}}{1+e^{-\beta\epsilon}} $$
Where $\beta$ is a positive constant.

I have to find what is the mean number of particle in the state $i$, $i=1,2$. Let's call this number $N_i$.
My reasoning is:

$$\mathbb{E}[N_i]=\sum\limits_{k=1}^Nk\mathbb{P}(N_i=k)$$

and $\mathbb{P}(k=N_i)$ is the probability that exactly $k$ particles are in the state $i$, i.e ${{N}\choose{k}} p_i^k p_j^{N-k}$. Thus, for $i=1$

$$\mathbb{E}[N_i]=\sum\limits_{k=1}^Nk{{N}\choose{k}}\left(\frac{1}{1+e^{-\beta\epsilon}}\right)^k\left(\frac{e^{-\beta\epsilon}}{1+e^{-\beta\epsilon}} \right)^{N-k}=\left(\frac{e^{-\beta\epsilon}}{1+e^{-\beta\epsilon}} \right)^{N}\sum\limits_{k=1}^Nk{{N}\choose{k}}e^{\beta\epsilon k}$$

Which is something difficult to calculate.
However the solution says

$$ \mathbb{E}[N_1]=Np_1=\frac{N}{1+e^{-\beta\epsilon}}$$

And the same for $i=2$.
Are the two equivalent? If not, what is my error?

EDIT: Mathematica says

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^Nk{{N}\choose{k}}e^{\beta\epsilon k}=e^{\beta\epsilon}(1+e^{\beta\epsilon})^{N-1}N$$
Thus $$ \mathbb{E}[N_1]=\left(\frac{e^{-\beta\epsilon}}{1+e^{-\beta\epsilon}} \right)^{N}e^{\beta\epsilon}(1+e^{\beta\epsilon})^{N-1}N$$
I don't see at all how to reduce this to $Np_1$

Comment: The probability that exactly $k$ particles are in state $i$ is $\binom{N}{k}p_i^k(1-p_i)^{N-k}$.

Comment: you mean $(1-p_j)^{N-k}$ right? And this complicates the thing even more. If it weren't for that $k$ I could use the binomial theorem, but like this I don't know how to proceed. I'll edit it in either way.

Comment: No, I mean $(1-p_i)^{N-k}$. Exacly $k$ particles in state $i$ (probability per particle is $p_i$), so exactly $N-k$ particles that are *not* in state $i$ (probability per particle is $1-p_i$). Further choosing $k$ particles from $N$ can be done on $\binom{N}{k}$ ways.

Comment: You are right. Thank you, the sum is now much easier, but I still doubt it will turn out equal to the other form

Comment: Here $\mathbb EN_i=Np_i$ for $i=1,2$ (expectation of [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)).

Comment: I still don't understand how to go from one to the other. Mathematica says $$ \sum\limits_{k=1}^N k{{N}\choose{k}}e^{\beta\epsilon k}=e^{\beta\epsilon}\left(1+e^{\beta\epsilon}\right)^{N-1}N$$so the sum doesn't equal $Np_1$

Comment: Also realize that $N_1+N_2=N$ so that $\mathbb EN_1+\mathbb EN_2=N$. That agrees with $\mathbb EN_i=Np_i$ for $i=1,2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{aligned}\sum_{k=1}^{N}k\binom{N}{k}\left(\frac{1}{1+r}\right)^{k}\left(\frac{r}{1+r}\right)^{N-k} & =\left(\frac{r}{1+r}\right)^{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N}k\binom{N}{k}r^{-k}\\
 & =N\left(\frac{r}{1+r}\right)^{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N}\binom{N-1}{k-1}r^{-k}\\
 & =N\left(\frac{r}{1+r}\right)^{N}r^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\binom{N-1}{k}r^{-k}\\
 & =N\left(\frac{r}{1+r}\right)^{N}r^{-1}\left(r^{-1}+1\right)^{N-1}\\
 & =N\frac{1}{1+r}
\end{aligned}
$$